# MySQL convert duplicate field entries to duplicate incrementing value

Tags: mysql, sql, select, mysql-workbench

I currently have a table that has a parent_id field for multiple entries, ie the same ID number for 4 entries (as per the screenshot below). I would like to convert the parent_id to run from 9000 upwards, so in the screenshot 000004 would become 9000 in 4 entries, 000007 would become 9001 in 4 entries and so on (as shown in the example outcome). Does anyone know of an easy way to implement this please as I'd rather not have to manually change 2224 entries!?

Thanks in advance guys!

Table screenshot:

[image: table screenshot]

Example outcome:

[image: example outcome]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want an `update`.  If so:

```
update t join
       (select t.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
        from t
       ) tt
       on t.id = tt.id
    set t.parent_id = 9000 + floor( (seqnum - 1) / 4);
```

Note that this ignores the current `parent_id`, assigning the same value to groups of 4 rows based on the `id`.

EDIT:

In older versions of MySQL:

```
update t join
       (select t.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as seqnum
        from (select t.* from t order by id) t cross join
             (select @rn := 0) params
       ) tt
       on t.id = tt.id
    set t.parent_id = 9000 + floor( (seqnum - 1) / 4);
```

Comment: Sorry, should have said, we are running MySQL Community 5.6.44 on AWS

Comment: @TomBromley . . . One of the reasons I used `row_number()` is because it is easy to convert to variables.  I added an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If you are runnig MySQL 8.0, you can use `dense_rank()` for this:

```
select
    t.*,
    8999 + dense_rank() over(order by parent_id) new_parent_id
from mytable t
```

On earlier versions, one (less efficient) option uses a correlated subquery:

```
select
    t.*,
    9000 + (select count(distinct t1.parent_i) from mytable t1 where t1.parent_id < t.parent_id) new_parent_id
from mytable t
```

Comment: Currently running on AWS under MySQL Community 5.6.44 (not my choice), is there a way to do it on this ver?

Comment: @TomBromley: ok, I updated my answer with a solution for ealier versions.